# Material UI let ToggleButtonGroup have fixed size independent of having content

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

I am trying to figure out how to keep all the buttons at the same size even if they are keeping no content.

This is the wanteds size, which works well as long as the top and bottom buttons keep some content:

[image]

If the middle button is set to Auto-mode, then the buttons are disbled and should not show any plus/minus sign to make clear its disabled for the user. But I can not figure out how to make sure the size is not changing.

Any ideas?

Unwanted state:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
style={{opacity: 0,}}
```

inside the Icon-tag fixes it.